# How to rotate an inline svg?

Tags: css, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/L1u83Lts/1/ <-- That is my inline svg code, it has some css inside already so when you hover over the parent div, #menu_btn, the path changes color, I would like to know if it would be possible to use css transform: rotate() with this svg? I've tried a few methods but I know I'm missing something.

Code here as well vvv

```
 <svg id="menu_svg" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="75px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="80px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <style>
            #menu_svg {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .menu_svg {
                fill: white;    
            }
            #menu_btn:hover + #menu_svg .menu_svg {
                fill: #FC0;
            }
        </style>
        <defs>
            <g id="menu_svg_cont">
                    <path d="M197.396,249.5c1.664,0,3.327,0.635,4.596,1.904L319.2,368.612c2.539,2.539,2.539,6.654,0,9.192    c-2.538,2.538-6.654,2.538-9.192,0L192.8,260.596c-2.539-2.539-2.539-6.654,0-9.192C194.069,250.135,195.732,249.5,197.396,249.5z    " />
                    <path d="M314.604,132.292c1.664,0,3.327,0.634,4.596,1.904c2.539,2.539,2.539,6.654,0,9.192L201.992,260.596    c-2.538,2.539-6.653,2.539-9.192,0c-2.539-2.539-2.539-6.654,0-9.192l117.208-117.208    C311.277,132.927,312.941,132.292,314.604,132.292z"/>
            </g>
        </defs>
        <g class="menu_svg">
            <use xlink:href="#menu_svg_cont"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```js
document.getElementById("menu_btn").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  
  document.getElementById("part1").beginElement();
  
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="menu_btn">Begin</button>

<svg id="menu_svg" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="75px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="80px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <style>
                #menu_svg {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
                .menu_svg {
                    fill: red; 
                }
                #menu_btn:hover + #menu_svg .menu_svg {
                    fill: #FC0;
                }
   </style>
            <defs>
                <g id="menu_svg_cont">
                        <path d="M197.396,249.5c1.664,0,3.327,0.635,4.596,1.904L319.2,368.612c2.539,2.539,2.539,6.654,0,9.192    c-2.538,2.538-6.654,2.538-9.192,0L192.8,260.596c-2.539-2.539-2.539-6.654,0-9.192C194.069,250.135,195.732,249.5,197.396,249.5z    " />
                        <path d="M314.604,132.292c1.664,0,3.327,0.634,4.596,1.904c2.539,2.539,2.539,6.654,0,9.192L201.992,260.596    c-2.538,2.539-6.653,2.539-9.192,0c-2.539-2.539-2.539-6.654,0-9.192l117.208-117.208    C311.277,132.927,312.941,132.292,314.604,132.292z"/>
                </g>
            </defs>
            <g class="menu_svg">
                <use xlink:href="#menu_svg_cont">
                  <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" id="part1"
                                    type="rotate" from="0 256 256" to="90 256 256"
                                    dur="0.5s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze"/>
                  <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" 
                                    type="rotate" from="90 256 256" to="0 256 256"
                                    dur="0.5s" begin="part1.end" fill="freeze" />
                </use>
            </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I need it to be animated on click, but this was still helpful, do you know how I might be able to animate it?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how to do SMIL animation.  You could also do it with SVG animation. However note that neither of these methods will work with IE.

Comment: Typo: when I said "SVG animation" two comments up, I meant "CSS animation".

Comment: Whoops, another speedbump, I need the animation to start when I click a totally different element (#menu_btn), I don't suppose there is a way to do that right?